# How can I get the index of the minimum values in a matrix, for each column and each row? in Python3

Tags: matrix, indexing, min

I have a matrix nxn in Python, and I know how to get the minimum value for each column, but I'd like to know how to get the index of these minimum values of each column.

This function below returns the minimum values for each column. Is there a way to return the INDEX of the minimum values of the columns?

```
x = [min(column) for column in zip(*Matrix)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
idx_and_mins = [ min(enumerate(column), key=lambda x: x[1])  for column in zip(*dist) ]
```

In this, we iterate on the columns using list comprehension on zip(*dist), then for each column we create a list of tuples of indexes and values `something like this [(0, 10), (1, 20), (2, 4)]`, then we pass this list to `min` function and set `key` param to a function returning first value of the tuple. This key function will be called by min each time when comparing 2 tuples of the list

Comment: Why should he try that? What does it do? How does it answer the question? Explain yourself!